# codenameone, error when build ios apps with google maps extension

Tags: ios, google-maps, build, codenameone

I tried to build condenameone project with googlemaps extension but it failed.
this is the error log :
The following build commands failed:

```
CompileC build/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/DanoneCodi/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/DanoneCodi.build/Release-iphoneos/DanoneCodi.build/Objects-normal/armv7/com_codename1_googlemaps_InternalNativeMapsImpl.o DanoneCodi-src/com_codename1_googlemaps_InternalNativeMapsImpl.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
Failed xcodebuild step
```

How to fix this?
further question, if I want to decided to remvoe the googlemaps extensions, how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

That's a partial log, we need the full log to help.

A common problem is developers including the cn1lib but not actually using it which fails as a callback collides with the optimizer that strips away unused parts.